# What does "Stick out my jaw" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Mom passed the salad bowl. “Beth, you’re sixteen,” she said. “You should know better than to ask a question like that.”
I rolled my eyes and **stuck out my jaw**. “Should I?”

Comment: drop jawed? ...

Comment: @Ibf nope, it's 'obstinate'.

Comment: Also refer https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+your+chin+out